# Cannot expand APFS container: "The target disk is too small for this operation"

Tags: partition, apfs

I have two partitions on my main drive, and I deleted the first one. Here's what I have:

```
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         700.2 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +700.2 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume MacOS High Sierra       478.0 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 39.9 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk2s4
```

```
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# gpt show -l /dev/disk0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2          4         Pri GPT table
          6      76800      1  GPT part - "EFI System Partition"
      76806   73242362         
   73319168  170957092      2  GPT part - ""
  244276260          4         Sec GPT table
  244276264          1         Sec GPT header
```

When I tried to expand the size of my APFS container, I get the following error:

```
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root [1]# diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s3 0
Started APFS operation
Error: -69771: The target disk is too small for this operation
```

Is there anyway to expand the apfs container without having to copy the container to an external disk, erase the disk, then copying it back?

Comment: You can not expand a APFS container to include free space above the container. If you could get the occupied space in the container down to under 300 GB, then you might be able to clone the existing APFS container to a new container created in the free space.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Why is that the case? In my understanding, there is a superblock, which contains information about where the metadata is. You can simply move the superblock to the start of the free space, keep the rest metadata where they are, and add the free space into the free block file.

Comment: Is your issue with copying to external drive and back that you don't *have* an external drive to backup to or speed concerns?  You could certainly use [GParted](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) to move the container to start of free space after the EFI partition and then expand it.  GParted has worked well for me to move APFS containers like this but it is slower than backing up and restoring and it would be risky to do without any backup at all in case it failed.

Comment: @lx07 My major concern is that it's slow. I only have a HDD with a write speed about 100 MB/s, so it probably will take a long time. (And in the meanwhile, I have to figure out how to continue doing my work). I'm not also sure if my hard drive has any bad blocks or is physically damaged (it sometimes freezes the system), although it is still working.

Comment: I do not know enough about APFS to reply to *why is that the case*. However, not being able to expand a partition upward is true for partitions containing file systems other than APFS. For example, JHFS+, NTFS, Ext4, FAT and ExFAT can not be expanded upwards. Normally, a drive should contain only one APFS container residing immediately after the hidden EFI partition. So there should never be a reason to expand upwards. In practice, there often is need for a second APFS container which can lead to your situation.